# Allign elements close enough

Tags: html, css

i need to allign element under RED arrow right under the element where BLACK arrow is pointed at. In other words how do i allign  element close enough to input like 2-5px.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4IeX.png

code is here

CSS

```
 form.loginform 

{  
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;   
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 

}


div.divbg

{
    width: 200px;  
    height: 167px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 30%;   
    margin-left: 40%;
    background-color: aliceblue;

}

a.register

{

    font-family: Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;

}

#pass 
{
    float: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel=StyleSheet href="loginstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="divbg">
            <form method="post" class="loginform">
            Логин  <div class="center"><input type="text" name="login"/></div><br/>
            <div id="pass">Пароль <div class="center"><input type="text" name="password"/></div><br/>
            <a href="#" class="register">хочу зарегистрироваться!</a><br/></div> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти"/><br/>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need code bro, give us your html/css.

Comment: div id pass is just for testing, i though that uniting and writing some selector can do the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `<br />` tag after the `#center` div. That is what is pushing it down. You also have some padding around the `input` tag; both of those issues are what is causing that space.

Your code:

```
 <div class="center"><input type="text" name="password"/></div><br/>
```

Remove that `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

1 Get a modern browser

2 Install firebug or use developers tools

3 check if the last input box (black arrow) has some margin-bottom or padding-bottom.

4 If yes, set it to 0 or a negative value

5 if No, check if the element with the red arrow has margin-top, and remove it or set a negative margin-top value.

Without code, It's not so easy to help you